# Link error when using source files not on the root project directory (files included in the search paths) (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, extern

I've been programing a template structure and after make it work I decided to use it on some other project. The template consists in two files. ListOctree.cpp and ListOctree.h.
While they compile and run just fine on their own (I can run the structure self-test).

When using them on the other project, both ListOctree.cpp/.h are on the ./Util directory but while Visual Studio seems to find the .h file (I can use the .h declarations anywhere on the project), it seems like it can't find the .cpp source file where all the code declared on the .h is declared.

The files are part of the project. ists tree is something like this:

```
program.cpp <-- includes "Util/ListOctree.h"
/Util
    ListOctree.cpp
    ListOctree.h
```

All the classes and functions from ListOctree belong to the Util namespace.

The error that Visual C++ throws is:
error LNK2019: símbolo externo "public: __thiscall Util::ListOctree::ListOctree(int)" (...) sin resolver ...

Aprox. in english:
error LNK2019: external symbol "public: __thiscall Util::ListOctree::ListOctree(int)" (...) not resolved ...

When rebuilding the solution the Util/ListOctree.cpp is compiled an the .obj file generated yet it seems not to be able to link it together

I can also post the .h file but I find it too long to post now.

Annex: where and how i'm using the .h file

```
#include "Util/ListOctree.h"
//...
void main (){
//...
    ListOctree<int>* a = new ListOctree<int>(8);
//...
}
```

Annex: Util/ListOctree.h

```
#ifndef __UTIL_LISTOCTREE
#define __UTIL_LISTOCTREE

//Conditional compilation flags

#undef _SELFTEST
#undef _DEBUG_LISTOCTREE

//Conditional compilation options
#ifdef _DEBUG_LISTOCTREE
 #undef  _DEALLOCATE_LISTS
 #define _SELFTEST
#endif

#ifdef _SELFTEST
 #include <iostream>
#endif

#ifdef _SELFTEST
 #include<assert.h>
#endif

#ifdef _DEBUG_LISTOCTREE
 #include <iostream>
#endif
/////////////////////////////////

#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <math.h>
#include <exception>

//Remind me to never do this again. (xYz,XYz,XYZ,xYZ,xyz,Xyz,XyZ,xyZ,)
//A CAPS character means positive in the axis while a
//Lowercase character means negative
//FIXME Never used I think.
#define _xyz sons[0]
#define _xyZ sons[1]
#define _xYz sons[2]
#define _xYZ sons[3]
#define _Xyz sons[4]
#define _XyZ sons[5]
#define _XYz sons[6]
#define _XYZ sons[7]

namespace Util{
/**
 * @brief The node class
 *
 * Each node stores up to 8 sons, a parent pointer and, if it
 * is a Leaf node, a list of contents.
 */
template <typename T> class Node{
    //Attributes
public:
    ///An array with all the sons
    Node<T>* sons[8];
    ///A parent pointer
    Node<T>* parent;

    //The node contents (if any)
    std::list<T>* c;

    //Methods
public:
    /// Deallocates itself AND all of it's sons
    ~Node();
    /// Creates an empty node
    Node();
    /// Creates a node with its eight sons and a parent reference from an 9 pointer array
    Node(Node<T>** nodes);
    ///Returns the node contents
    std::list<T>* getContents(){return c;};
    ///Pushes an item into the node
    void pushItem(T item);
    ///Removes an item from the node
    void eraseItem(T item){c->erase(item);};
    ///Clears the node contents
    void clearNode(){c->clear();};
};

/**
 * @brief Container for @see Node classes
 *
 * This class allows a more convenient way of working with Octrees
 */
template <typename T> class ListOctree {
    //Attributes
private:
    int width;
    Node<T>* root;

    //Methods
public:
    ListOctree(int width);
    ~ListOctree();
    void pushItemAt(T item, int x, int y, int z);
    void eraseItemAt(T item, int x, int y, int z);
    void clearItemsAt(int x, int y, int z);
    std::list<T>* getItems();
    std::list<T>* operator() (int x, int y, int z){return(getItemsAt(x,y,z));};
    std::list<T>* getItemsAt(int x, int y, int z);
private:
    char nextNode(int x, int y, int z, int* cx, int* cy, int* cz, int width, Node<T>* n, bool createNew) throw(...);
    void _pushItemAt(T item, int x, int y, int z, int cx, int cy, int cz, int width, Node<T>* n);
    void _eraseItemAt(T item, int x, int y, int z, int cx, int cy, int cz, int width, Node<T>* n);
    void _clearItemsAt(int x, int y, int z, int cx, int cy, int cz, int width, Node<T>* n);
    std::list<T>* _getItemsAt(int x, int y, int z, int cx, int cy, int cz, int width, Node<T>* n);
    void prune(Node<T>* n);
    void addItemsToList(std::list<T>* lst, Node<T>* n);
};

/**
 * @brief Exception used internally
 * 
 * FIXME, never used, can't be used for some reason
 */
class ListOctreeException : public std::exception{
private:
    std::string msg;

public:
    ListOctreeException(){msg="ListOctreeException";};
    ListOctreeException(std::string s){msg=s;};
    const char* what(){return(msg.c_str());};
};
};//namespace
#endif
```

Comment: Post both the header and the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration and the definition of templates should be kept in the same file (usually the .h).  See [the FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12) for details (it's also technically possible to instantiate the template in a file that #includes the implementation ([see this also](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13))).

The keyword `export` that was supposed to be used in the case where the two are separated, but few compilers implemented it, and it has now been removed in c++0x.

Comment: So all the template code must be inserted into the .h file? The .cpp is rather large.

Also. would work to do something like:
cat ListOctree.h ListOctree.cpp > ListOctree_new.h
Then including the new file.

Comment: @NeonMan Yes, and then the .h can be included.

Comment: @NeonMan Yes, that would work too, but then you wouldn't include `ListOctree.cpp` in the project.

Comment: @jonsca Thankyou! Tried that just after posting it and it does work. Now the program includes ListOctree_fat.h which includes both the original .h and the .cpp (Can't upboat yet)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a reference between the projects in your solution? (Visual Studio 2010)

Right Click Project->References

Or, have you added a project dependency? (Visual Studio 2008)

Comment: The files are part of the project. One Solution with one project. Didn't try to use multiple projects

Comment: You should clarify that in your question then. You state, "when using them on the other project ...".

Comment: But since that is not the issue, we won't be able to help you without seeing some of your source code.

Comment: Added the .h file and how i'm using it on the .cpp. still it is odd that the compiler can compile (redundancy ;) but the the generated code can't be linked even though they are part of the same project (edit, i know list->erase(item) is wrong, but the method is not used. I need to remove it from the node class)